# can user qbasic functions return a string?

Tags: basic, qbasic, qb64

```
FUNCTION QUAD_NAME (X, Y, Z AS INTEGER)   
QUAD_NAME = string_var
```

returns a "illegal string-number conversion"

I checked the in IDE help on function command (currently using QB64, but their wiki is down), but no information as to whether it can return a string. 
Currently I am using a global var to assign the quad_name but would prefer to use a function to return the desired var.

EDIT: QB64 Server is back up (forums, wiki). will check there too. If no answer here, I'll post what I find.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it does

Need to change the function var to a "$" and the return var with a "$"

change the above to

```
FUNCTION QUAD_NAME$ (X, Y, Z AS INTEGER)   
    QUAD_NAME$ = string_var$
END FUNCTION
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also probably declare all function parameters:

```
FUNCTION QUAD_NAME$ (X AS INTEGER, Y AS INTEGER, Z AS INTEGER)   
    QUAD_NAME$ = string_var$
END FUNCTION
```

Comment: Yup, running that as is would have error out, I only have it that way for posting simplicity :-)

Comment: You should always terminate your SUBS and FUNCTIONS :>

Comment: maybe I should put a header that says "pseudo code" :-)